# Can I enter missing responses as a covariate in ANOVA when compare across groups?

Tags: missing-data, statsmodels

I have a dataset collected from 3 groups of clinical samples. I want to compare measures among 3 groups but each group has substantial missing responses. What are the strategies for handling missing responses in medical research? Will it make sense if entering the missing response rate as a covariate when running ANOVAs? Any advice will be greatly appreciated!